# Сортировка по нескольким полям в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, сортировка

Возможна ли сортировка в wordpress по нескольким мета полям? 
Нужно сделать вот такую сортировку:

1-ми выводятся посты у которых поле recommend отличное от нуля (чем больше значение, тем выше они в списке).

2-ми выводятся посты по полю rating.

3-ми выводятся посты у которых и recommend = 0 и rating = 0 (сортировка по алфавиту).

Получается только по одному полю сортировать, при указании второго ничего не меняется...

Код:

```
$args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'companies',
                    'location'    => $term,
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        'recommend' => array(
                            'key' => 'recommend',
                        ),
                        'rating' => array(
                            'key' => 'rating',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'orderby'    => array(
                    'recommend' => 'DESC',
                    'rating' => 'DESC',
                    'meta_value_num' => 'DESC',
                    'title' => 'ASC'
                    ),
                    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
                );
```

Хоть поле recommend и указываю первым, по нему все равно не сортирует. Сначала выводятся посты с сортировкой по рейтингу, потом по алфавиту, поле recommend не учитывается почему-то.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде проблема решилась, просто изменил 'relation' => 'OR', на 'relation' => 'AND' и стало сортировать как нужно.